# How is this もって used?

Tags: grammar, jlpt

I have this sentence as an example for the grammar point `をもって`:

`I国が起こした戦争は、世界中に衝撃をもって伝えられた。`

`をもって`　can either refer to [1] the means through which something is done, or [2] a point in time where something ends/begins.

I'm not really sure which usage this is. As far as I can figure out, it's either something like [1] "The world found out about the war in Country X with a shock/suddenly", or [2] "When the war broke out suddenly (with a crash/bang) in Country X, the world found out about it."

Or, more likely, none of the above. Can someone shed some light on what I'm missing?

Comment: How about "When Country X started the war, the world found out about it with a shock" as a translation? Or, "The war started by Country X was reported around the world with shock"? This Japanese dictionary shows 5 meanings of もって（以て）. http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BB%A5%E3%81%A6

Comment: @Gradius, yeah those were poor translations, I was more trying to nail down the actual meaning. I'll take it you think it's the former meaning [1]?

Comment: It's similar to [1]. However, obviously it's not a "means" but rather a status or circumstance. I think the explanation in the textbook or dictionary you are using cannot be applied exactly in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it means something like:

> `I国`が起こした戦争は、世界中に衝撃**をもって**伝えられた。
>   The war which `country I` initiated was conveyed to the world with a shock.
>   The world was taken aback when told of the war which `country I` initiated.

According to [this oshiete question](http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/6839007.html), `衝撃をもって` has the same meaning as `衝撃と共に` and `衝撃を伴って`, or "together with shock"/"accompanied by shock".